# Can I use conditional assignment when 0 is a valid value?

Tags: javascript

For example I want to take an input, and conditionally set it to another variable if it's a number.

I want to do something like

```
var x = input || "default value"
```

where I can set a default if input is undefined.  However,  I expect input to be a number, and in the case of `input == 0`, I want `x==0`.

I know that I could use a ternary operator and do something like

```
var x = typeof(input) !== "undefined" ? input : "default value"
```

is there a less verbose way to do this?

Comment: what do you mean "cleaner"

Comment: `var x = input != null ? input : 'default'` because `null == undefined`

Comment: by "cleaner" I mean less verbose

Answer (score 1):

The most practical less verbose way I know is to use a helper function

```
function def(input, defvalue){
   return (typeof(input) !== "undefined" ? input : "default value");
}

var x = def(input, "default");
```

but it evaluates the default value even if you don`t end up using it so the semantics are slightly different.

Other than that, I think Coffeescript has a couple of [operators](http://coffeescript.org/#operators) for doing what you want but they consider null and undefined to be equivalent (so the equivalent JS would be `input != null ? input : defvalue`).

Answer (score 1):

> I want to take an input, and conditionally set it to another variable if it's a number.

```
var x = isFinite(input) ? input : "default value";
```

Caution: if input is null then it will still set `x` to null. But perhaps this is what you are looking for - not sure how much shorter it can get.

Comment: +1 Maybe do `+input` to coerce the value to a number in case of `null` or the other coercible non-numbers.

Answer (score 0):

if you're expecting a `number` type and wish to set `x` to a default value otherwise, you can try this:

```
var x = (input === +input) ? input : "default value";
```

The `+` operator attempts to convert `input` into a number type. If it's not a number, it will return `NaN`. If it is a number, but `input` is really a string, then the strict `===` identity comparison will return false.

The problem with doing this:

```
var x = typeof(input) !== "undefined" ? input : "default value"
```

is that `null` will be treated as a valid input because `typeof(null)` is `object`.